# How to list only "normal" readable folder (not compressed ones for instance)?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make simple repetitive operations in a directory containing folders, such as copy/paste or rename files in each of these folders. My problem is that by using `ls -d` command, it considers not only the "normal folders" but the `.tar` or `.bz2` too. This causes problems for the operations I make within the folders.

I tried to list these folders by different way using limiting parameters such as size or existence of a specific character, but my directory contains thousands of folders with very different names and size of the names... Then my "particular" solutions doesn't work so much, excluding some folders I need.

```
for i in $(ls -d 2015*)
   do 
     cp -v file_Iwant_2_Copy "Place_2_copyIt_$i"
     cd ../
done
```

What I need is that in my variable `i`, only the non-compressed folders are listed. Using `ls -d`, the `.bz2` are considered, leading to an error after when I try to "enter in" such as:

> "XXX.bz2 is not a folder, impossible to access"

Thank you for your precious help

Comment: please note that the `-d` option on `ls` does *not* mean "list only directories" which seems to be what you are expecting; what it means is "list directories as themselves"; the normal thing for `ls` to do with a argument that is a directory is to list the *contents* of that directory; e.g., compare `ls .` with `ls -d .`

Comment: also, please note that `.tar`, `.bz2`, and other compressed files are *not* "compressed folders" from the system's point-of-view; conceptually, they are sometimes like folders if they contain a tree-like collection of files; but a compressed file might just be a single file compressed down; in fact, from the system's point of view, everything is a *file*, **including** directories; it's just that the content of a directory is a set of references to other files

Comment: Thank you very much landru27 for your explanations, now I understand really clearer what was happening with this command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if it's a directory with `if [ -d "$i" ]`.

```
for i in 2015*
do 
    if [ -d "$i" ]
    then
        cp -v file_Iwant_2_Copy "Place_2_copyIt_$i"
    fi
done
```

There's no reason to use `ls -d`, just use the wildcard directly. See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)

And you shouldn't use `cd ..` in the loop. If the file is in the current directory of the first iteration, it won't be in the parent directory. And then each iteration will move up another level, getting further from where the file is.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, your solution is probably the simplest and efficient way to do what I want. I have read the link you put on the problems parsing ls, and, even if some steps are too advanced for the Shell beginner I am, I think I understood why it can be problematic to use ls, mainly in operative loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
for i in $(ls -1 | grep -ivE "2015.*\.(tar|bz2)$"); do 
    echo "copying $i"
    cp "$i" "${i}_mod" 
done
```

grep flags meanings:

`-i` case insensitive

`-v` select non-matching lines

`-E` PATTERN is an extended regular expression

Comment: Thank you Perplexabot, your code and explanations are very useful! I though that the `grep` function should resolve my problem (mainly if I know what kind of file/folder/extension I want/don't want), but the syntax to use it confidently, with the system of pipes, is somewhat complex when you are beginning. The solution of @Barmar is simpliest for the problem described, but without any doubt for further operations I will make on my database the use `grep` should be salutary! ;)  Thank you all @Perplexabot @Barmar and @landru27 to solve my problem quickly and with explanations!

Comment: That's not a valid regular expression, you need something before `*`. You're confusing regexp and glob.

Comment: There's no need for `.*`. If it matches `.*tar` it also matches `tar`.